# How can I prohibit other Linux Kernel modules to get access to some regular files?

Tags: c, linux, security, linux-kernel

The problem is to prohibit access to some files (files from my "blacklist"). It implies that nobody besides me (my own kernel module) can either read or modify these files.

I've already asked this question here, on StackOverflow, but I haven't gotten an answer. There was only one solution offered to change file's permissions and file's owner. However, it isn't enough for my goals, since file's permissions as well as file's owner can be easily modified by someone else.

But I haven't given up, I've carried on studying this problem.

I replaced some fields of the system calls table by the pointers to my own functions. Thus I managed to prohibit any USER module to get an access to the files from my blacklist; in addition, this approach doesn't depend on file's permissions or file's owner. However, the key word is "user modules". I mean that any kernel module still can easily get an access to the files from my blacklist via calling, for instance, the `filp_open()` function. I looked through the Linux code sources and it turned out that all these system calls that I hooked (`open`, `openat`, ...) are simple wrappers and no more.

Could you help me? Is there a way to do something with `filp_open` that is similar to what I've done with system calls? Any other solutions (without hooking) are welcome.

Comment: No, this is absolutely not possible. You need isolated hardware.

Comment: Blocking access to a set of files is not your problem... it's your solution to a problem you haven't told us anything about. If you told us **why** you want to do that (i.e. what the actual problem is), we might be able to offer a different solution.

Comment: Very well said @FelixG, this looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Okay, I'll try to explain it more detaily. There are modules (I'm not responsible for them, they were designed by other programmists) that store their configuration data in files (since there is no registry in Linux). My kernel module must protect these files with configuration data from any external modification. Of course, some modifications are allowed but only through my module (ioctls request); however it is already other part of work, now I just look for a way to prohibit all external modules to get access to these files.

Comment: So those other modules are regular user-space applications, and your kernel-module is supposed to protect their configuration files, correct? But these applications still access their files normally, or are all modifications done through your module?

Comment: Other modules are both user-space applications and kernel modules. My kernel module is supposed to protect their configuration files. All modifications are done though my module.

Comment: @StaTik I see there's a problem of terminology here. 1) Userspace applications are ***not*** modules, they are userspace applications. Kernel modules are a different thing. 2) Why should you worry about other pre-existing kernel modules modifying your files? Why should they? It makes no sense. 3) Refer to my answer below as to why even "protecting" from userspace is not that simple.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli, 1) Okay, I got it.

Comment: 2) I have an example for you. Although it refers to Windows, I hope that it demonstrates the main idea. Some antivirus programs prohibit anyone to get an access to the registry key where they store their configuration data. It means that even if you try to open the key via calling some kernel mode function like ZwOpenKey, you'll get an access error. Will some pre-existing kernel modules try to modify this registry key? Obviously, no. On the other hand, such attack is still possible. Maybe not from the system, but from someone else.

Comment: Honestly, I've tried to do it myself once) I needed to turn off some feature that my antivirus had. I didn't manage to do this because of the protection mentioned above.

Comment: 3) I still don't understand why my hooks won't protect my files from user-space applications? I've read your answer below, but it didn't help. As I understand, all user-space applications accomplish IO-operations via calling system calls. Am I right? And I replaced these system calls by my own functions. So as I understand, while my kernel module is loaded in the system, all user-space applications will use my functions. Or did you mean that my module may be unloaded at any moment?

Comment: @StaTik yes, your module can be unloaded, or worse, as I said in my answer, a new module can be loaded that takes control over your original one. The analogy with your Windows example is that an high privilege user could very well disable the Antivirus and change the keys.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, It isn't still clear for me. As for my Windows example, disabling the Antivirus doesn't affect on getting access to this registry key at all, as I know. It is an internal feature and developers decided not to allow users to control it. It means that even if you turn off Antivirus, you won't manage to get access to this key. The only possible way to modify this registry key is to find out the driver that protect the key and to unload it from the system.
And as for Linux, what do you mean by "takes control over your original one"?

Comment: @StaTik well I am not a Windows expert so I can't really argue about that, I suppose you would know better than me. On Linux though, what I mean by "takes control" is that a newly inserted module could very well restore the original syscalls and undo any changes your module did.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, but where will this new module take original system calls from? I've already  changed them. Or do they store somewhere else?

Comment: @StaTik you've merely modified a pointer in the system call table, it's a very easily reversible operation, just a matter of resolving the appropriate `sys_xxx` symbol and putting it back (see for example `sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep -i sys_open`). And even if it wasn't that easy, those syscalls could very well be re-implemented by the module itself.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, thanks, now it's clear for me.

Comment: @StaTik with requirements like that, you'll likely need separate hardware with encrypted storage, or at the very least your code needs to be installed at a lower level than the OS itself. That's because, as Marco Bonelli has already stated, you can't reliably protect yourself from (other parts of) the operating system, if you're running inside it. Things get easier if you can live with the risk of other modules/processes possibly damaging those files, because then all you need is encryption (to prevent reading them)

Comment: @FelixG, okay, I got it. I think that encryption isn't an appropriate solution here since as you've noticed it doesn't protect files from modifying. Honestly, I'm a bit shocked) Exclusive access to a regular file seems to be one of the most necessary features of any file system, however, in Linux this feature isn't realized.

Comment: I'm thinking about another possible solution now. Let my module stores the etalon contents of the file in the memory, periodically calculates the checksum of the file and compares it with the etalon value and if it's different, my module replaces the contents of the file by etalon one.

Comment: If some trusted user-space application or kernel module wants to modify a "protected" file, it'll have to send some requests to my module. My module will write new data to the file, save the data for itself and recalculate a checksum.

Comment: This would be a possible solution, but it can still be circumvented by a user with root access, by simply unloading your module. As soon as you're root, you can do pretty much anything you want.

Comment: By the way, regular locking of files is of course easily possible in linux on a filesystem/kernel level. So a process can indeed prevent other processes from accessing its own files. However, these locks can still be removed by the root user. For information on mandatory locking, see https://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible. *Theoretically*, this *could* be achieved by running the kernel under a custom-made [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) or running on custom-made hardware, but it would be *extremely complicated* (if not impossible) to achieve in reality.

You cannot protect the kernel from itself. In any normal scenario (i.e. no dedicated hardware or hypervisor), the Linux kernel runs at the highest privilege level on the machine, and can therefore revert any changes you make if it wants. If your module needs to deny access to some file *to the whole kernel*, then there's really something conceptually wrong about what you are doing. Moreover, you seem to be assuming that other kernel modules would be somehow "interested" in messing with your module: why would that be the case?

Furthermore, even changing permissions or overriding syscalls does not solve any problem: unless you *correctly* configure [kernel lockdown](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=aefcf2f4b58155d27340ba5f9ddbe9513da8286d) (kernel >= v5.4) and/or some other security measure like [module signing](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/module-signing.html) (and ideally also secure boot), the `root` user is always able to insert modules and subvert your "security" measures.

If you need to deprive `root` of access to these files, then as I said there's really something logically wrong. The `root` user can already do whatever it wants with whichever configuration file it wants, of course destroying important configuration files is going to break the system, but that's not really something that you can avoid. Assuming that `root` is evil doesn't make much sense as a threat model in any normal scenario.

Comment: Okay. But what if some process wanna be the only one who has a write permission to some file. For instance, the data that the process intends to write is of so great importance that the process wanna be sure that nobody will interfere him. Is there really no way to achive it in Linux? Are there really no mechanisms of synchronization provided for this case?

Comment: @StaTik there is absolutely *no way* to do that. Not only in Linux, but probably also in any other operating system. As I said, you cannot protect the kernel from itself. If whatever you are trying to accomplish needs to rely on something like that, then it is fundamentally flawed and cannot work.